# Output versionName property during build

Tags: android, gradle

Android project's `build.gradle` says `versionName "foo"`

How can I get gradle to echo that value of `versionName` at build time?

`gradlew properties` reports a lot of stuff, but there's no `foo` & it says `version: unspecified`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android plugin DSL appears to only be available as a [download](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html) but following an inspection the following should do something like what you want:

```
task printMeVersion << {
  out.print(android.defaultConfig.versionName)
}
```